# Restore a constant in javascript based on a block of code

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an interesting problem and I need help solving it. Thanks in advance, I would appreciate any answer.
*A colleague sent you a file, but you can't find the VECTOR_NAME constant anywhere. You need to restore it based on this block of code.*

```
const getVector = ({x, y}) => {
    if (x > y) {
        if (Math.abs(x / y) < THRESHOLD) return;
        return x > 0 ? 3 : 1;
    } else {
        if (Math.abs(y / x) < THRESHOLD) return;
        return y > 0 ? 2 : 0;
    }
};

let v = getVector({x: _x, y: _y});
if (v && VECTOR_NAME.indexOf(v) !== -1) {
    ev.emit('event.' + VECTOR_NAME[v]);
}

ev.on('event.up', () => {
    console.log('Amazing, something is moving up!');
});
```

Comment: It's `["up","down","left","right"]`

Comment: um.. yea im lost.. im seeing a whole pack of unknowns but for an answer so specific @JeremyThille im gonna sit back and watch the explaination

Comment: `'event.up'` comes from `'event.' + VECTOR_NAME[v]`. `v` is a number output by `getVector()`, which can only return one of 4 numbers : `0,1,2,3`. So we have `VECTOR_NAME = [ "up" , something, something, something ]`. With "up" and vectors (directions) I can only assume `["up","down","left","right"]`. Not necessarily in this order though.

Comment: I don't know how to put it right. Bring back or put back maybe?

Comment: it can also return `undefined` if (x/y) < THRESHOLD.. but i follow ur logic.. so it's a puzzle thingy and not a certain thing huh

Comment: Of course it's a puzzle. Sounds like homework. Actually it is `["down","left","up","right"]` because in getVector(), if the dominant number is `x` and it's positive, we pick the 3rd element (x>0 means 'right direction'). If it's negative, we pick the 1st element (left). If `y` is dominant and positive (up) it's item 2, and if it's negative (down) item 0.

Comment: (IMO sounds more like a take-home programming test for a job. Either way--throwing out answers instead of providing direction seems counter-productive in the long run.)

Comment: ah... not so sure as to the order of the words but i know this.. `getVector({x:0,y:0})==0`, `getVector({x:0,y:-1})==1`, `getVector({x:0,y:1})==2`, `getVector({x:1,y:0})==3` :D

Answer (score 0):

If VECTOR_NAME is ["down","left","up","right"], the result value of VECTOR_NAME.indexOf(v) !== -1 cannot be retrieved correctly. How to explain this.

Comment: You are right, that is the question. I don't understand too